# CORS request not http

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, cross-origin-read-blocking

I want to convert all the SVG paths in a SVG file to SVG polygons.

I want to iterate through all the paths in a given file, where the paths have different id values. I would also like to extract the id value. (Path converted to polygon should have the same original id value.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
<h1>SVG paths to polygons</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "file:///C:/Users/Temp/Desktop/input.svg", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml");
request.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  var response = event.target.responseText;
  var doc = new DOMParser();
  console.log("Document Loaded!");
  var allPaths =  Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll("path"));
  for(path in allPaths) {
    var polygon = doc.createElement("polygon");
    polygon.setAttribute("id", allPaths[path].getAttribute("id"));
    console.log("Converting " + allPaths[path].getAttribute("id"));
    var len = allPaths[path].getTotalLength();
    var p = allPaths[path].getPointAtLength(0);
    var seg = allPaths[path].getPathSegAtLength(0);
    var stp=p.x+","+p.y;

    for(var i=1; i<len; i++){

        p=allPaths[path].getPointAtLength(i);

        if (allPaths[path].getPathSegAtLength(i)>seg) {

        stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
        seg = allPaths[path].getPathSegAtLength(i);
        }
    }
    polygon.setAttribute("points", stp);
    allPaths[path].replaceWith(polygon);
    }
});
request.send();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

This code does not change anything in "input.svg".
It gives me a CORS request not http error and doesn't allow me to read the file on my own system Desktop.

How can I read the SVG file from my own Desktop(Windows 10)?

Comment: Did you try placing the file you are requesting inside your project directory ?

Comment: I tried putting them both on Desktop, then shifted to different directories. Both cases gave the same error.

Comment: Did you try getting this request in postman? If yes, can you print here all response?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what is postman.

Comment: Browsers have generally tightened up security recently and won't allow this. You can't read a different file if you load a file via the filesystem. You'd need to use a different tool.

Comment: Never mind, I finally got it to work. Sadly, the system doesn't allow me to post the answer.